# Zabbix 2.2.1 JBoss monitoring

Tags: zabbix

I created items for JBoss that has monitored data sources:

```
Name: JNDI name
Type: JMX agent
Key: jmx["jboss.as:type=datasources,name=readOnly","jndiName"]
Host interface: <your_to_monitor_host>:9999
User name: {$LOGIN}
Password: {$PASSWORD}
Type of information: Text
New application: JBoss EAP 6 JNDI String
```

However, there are some problems, in zabbix Item is identified as not supported. I checked the logs "**zabbix_java_gateway.log**" and Item not even started. Does anyone have some idea how to solve this problem?

Regards
Mick

Comment: In the item list for a host, if you point your mouse to the red cross in the "Error" column, what does it say?

Comment: jboss.as:type=datasources

Comment: o.k done, I found a solution, the key was bad,
correct key is : jmx["jboss.as:subsystem=datasources,data-source=socle-ds,statistics=pool","ActiveCount"]